# ms-access 2007 .exe

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-office

I have created a program in ms-access 2007, (in house program). Is it possible to create a stand alone program from access (.exe)?

Answer (score 6):

You can't. But you can use an Access runtime instead to run you project on the systems where there is no Access installed. Everything you have to do is to supply your clients runtime installation and copy of your project. Of course you can prepare a nice installation program to accomplish the task and install the whole solution smoothly without client's/your attention with just only few clicks.

Take a look at: [Access 2007 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d9ae78d9-9dc6-4b38-9fa6-2c745a175aed&displaylang=en)

There is a nice difference between runtime for Access 2007 and older versions. Currently you can have the runtime installation for free (for you and your clients), instead of paying for Access 2003 development tools (and also runtime components).

Answer (score 3):

Question was also asked here:

[access 2007 to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187833/access-2007-to-exe).  The question is pretty thoroughly explored there.

Seth

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here

[Overview of Packaging Access 2003 Applications](http://www.utteraccess.com/forums/showflat.php?Cat=&Number=496338&page=&view=&sb=5&o=&vc=1)

Its for MS Access 2003 but i think should be valid for 2007 as well.

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated there is a free Access 2007 runtime which you can download.  For more information on it see [Microsoft Office Access 2007 Developer Edition FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/developeredition2007faq.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has published an developer's extension for Access. This extension will help you to package the Access Runtime and your application together in a convenient installer. You can find out more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb229700.aspx